# How to set the column width for individual column in excel using data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, epplus

I have to export the data to excel. The width of the column are defined as the specification. The width must be exactly the same as defined when export to excel.

I wanted to define using Width as Data Attribute on property for the model.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false)]
internal class ColumnWidthAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    private int _width;
    public ColumnWidthAttribute(int width)
    {
        _width = width;
    }

    public virtual int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return _width;
        }
    }
}
```

Model Class:

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
[ColumnWidth(12)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

The code to export to excel.

```
using (var excelFile = new ExcelPackage())
{
    excelFile.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Bulk Upload";
    var worksheet = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    worksheet.Cells["A1"]
        .LoadFromCollection(Collection: items, PrintHeaders: true);
    response = excelFile.GetAsByteArray();
}
```

Here in above code i wanted to loop over collection and add the worksheet width according to the data attributes defined on the property. Can you guide me on how to loop over the data attribute and provide the width of the worksheet?

For example as in the `First name`, i wanted to display the length of column only have 12 characters only(whatever the length supplied from the database) and the width must be as defined in the data annotations. I have the specifications as shown below:

`Position   Length       Field
    1-12          12      First Name
    13-21         9       Last Name
    22-27         8       DOB`

The output i am getting currently:

[image]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show an example of the output it is producing, and the exact output you **want** to produce.

Comment: Could you further define "does not work"?